# iphone - requires expression of scalar type?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this method on the delegate

```
- (BOOL) isBook:(int)number {
    if (  ((number >= 0) && (number < 73)) ||
            ((number >= 432) && (number < 2864)) ) { 
        return YES; 
    }

    return NO;
}
```

then I have this call on the class (yes the class has a delegate protocol declared).

```
if ([delegate isBook:number]) {
  //do stuff
}
```

I have an error on this IF saying: **error: statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)** ??????????

I have tried to do

```
if ([delegate isBook:numnber] == YES)
```

but it gives me another error: **invalid operands to binary expression ('void' and 'int')**

Why is that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your protocol is expressing that method as this:

```
- (void)isBook:(int)number;
```

Then that's most likely how you get the error; change it so it returns `BOOL` like your implementation.

Comment: Duuuhhhhhhhhhhh!!!!!!! obviously. Thanks. That's it. I am reading but I was not seeing... :(